# html and javascript on a simiple table

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am doing a basic course for web development. I used html for creating a very simple table with 2 columns: Apples and fruits. Fruits should be the number of apples + 5 (basic approach for a better comprehension). I tried to add an addeventlistener as well

```js
var apples = document.getElementById('apples');
var fruits = document.getElementById('fruits');

function calculate() {
  fruits = apples + 5;
  fruits.innerHTML = fruits;
}
// Get all the input columns
var inputElement = document.getElementById('apples');
// Add Event Listeners to all the input columns
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
```

```html
<table class="egt">
  <tr>
    <th>apples</th>
    <th>fruits</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="apples">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fruits">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't get the "8" on the column "fruits". Am I missing something in the code? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Use fruits.value, input fields are field with value not innerHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Input values are updated on `value` attribute on `input` tag. So it is needed to get value like `fruits.value` and `apple.value`.
- And `apples.value` is string so for sum operation, it is needed to convert it to number.

```js
var apples = document.getElementById('apples');
var fruits = document.getElementById('fruits');

function calculate() {
  fruits.value = Number(apples.value) + 5;
}
// Get all the input columns
var inputElement = document.getElementById('apples');
// Add Event Listeners to all the input columns
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
```

```html
<table class="egt">
  <tr>
    <th>apples</th>
    <th>fruits</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="apples">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fruits">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks - I typed my answer on my phone - and byt the time i got to the computer to update to a real answer - you had produced this - which is basically the same as what I was going to o - I was going to use parseInt() insteado f number - but I will delete my answer since yours is complete and identical to what I was gonig to do.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var fruits = document.getElementById('fruits');

function calculate(event) {
//use event here to get the apples element value on every change event.target.value so you dont have to fetch the element every time
  fruits.value = (parseInt(event.target.value) + 5);
  //parse it as nummber and + 5
}

var inputElement = document.getElementById('apples');
inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
```

```html
<table class="egt">
  <tr>
    <th>apples</th>
    <th>fruits</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="apples">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" id="fruits">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Read here how to [target Event Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp)

And also read about [JavaScript parseInt() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Get the string value from `apples.value` and use `parseInt` to convert to an integer then update the fruits.

```js
var apples = document.getElementById('apples');
var fruits = document.getElementById('fruits');
  
  function calculate() {
    fruits.value = parseInt(apples.value) + 5;
  }
  // Get all the input columns
  var inputElement = document.getElementById('apples');
  // Add Event Listeners to all the input columns
  inputElement.addEventListener('change', calculate);
```

```html
<table class="egt">
        <tr>
          <th>apples</th>
          <th>fruits</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="apples">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" id="fruits">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```